# center div inside another div with absolute position

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a div to be centered inside another div even as it resizes,

and if more than one div with class `'inside'` is in the `'outside'` div, then they should go next to each other centered if there is enough room, otherwise slide beneath each other.

The following works:

```
#outside {
 width: 100%;
 text-align:center
}
.inside {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 32%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

but I want the same effect where the `.inside` element has a `position:absolute`

is this possible?

here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/172on5sb/

Comment: Can you create an [example](//jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: sure give me a minute

Comment: Centered how? Horizontally? Vertically? Both?

Comment: I added an example in the question

Comment: If you assign `position: absolute` to the `.inside` child elements, then they are taken out of the content flow.  Consequently, they are not aware of each other as siblings, and they will not behave as you might expect for inline or floated elements.  To accomplish this in CSS, you would have to make the CSS rules dependent on the known dimensions of the `.inside` elements and know in advance, how many their are.  You may have better luck using JavaScript to achieve the positioning.

Comment: @MarcAudet I was just thinking that this will probably have to be done in JS instead of just CSS, and your comment confirms that! thanks

Comment: @AbdulAhmad Was there any reason that you didn't want to simply make a parent div with dimensions inside of both of those boxes and center that?

Comment: yea there was a reason, but its a complicated reason : ) I think that will happen eventually but not right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the necessity of having to use attribute `position` set to `absolute`. Why not just use `position: relative`? It acts in a very similar manner. You can then center it by setting the parent to `text-align: center` and the child (itself) to `margin: auto`.

Bam, centered `div`.

**Edit:** According to what OP wanted:

`<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
<div style="position: relative; left: -50%;`

It's a hack, but it works fine.

Comment: because that's what I want. I know there are other ways, but this is what I'm trying to accomplish. For the record, the down vote isn't mine

Comment: I don't see any downvote, but fair enough. @AbdulAhmad

Comment: By the way, even though it might not be what you want in this case, the feature was created in CSS for that purpose, to differ from absolute. @AbdulAhmad

Comment: yea I see that.. I guess I'll need a different solution

Comment: Check out my edited answer, I tried giving you with an alternative. @AbdulAhmad